# How can we call a function in one maui app from another maui app

Tags: c#, maui

Let's say I have created two dotnet maui app,in one maui app I have defined a function by creating a class and defining  a function in it ,the class in the main directory.Now I have created another maui app and this maui app has  a button, I want it so,that when we click on the button in the maui app,then it should call the function defined in another maui app.
Next I have another maui app in macos,and the I have one a function defined in the app just like in the windows app,and I want to achieve same thing with it,i.e when I click on the button it should call the function .
How can I make it happen

I tried to load a dl file for windows (static linking) but that is not a correct solution because we are just providing the refrence to the dll file in windows app.

Comment: There is no way to just do that. You need to implement some sort of interprogram communication: REST API, gRPC, whatever. The subject is too broad for a stackoverflow question.

Comment: I suggest SignalR. The implementation for what you seek is 3 lines of code in the hub.

Comment: You could use SSL/TSL or SignalR. When you press the button it sends a signal which calls your function.